# Question on the Definition of Differential 1-Form of Tu's Textbook

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I have two questions on chapter 4.1(pg. 34-35) of Tu's Textbook \textit{An Introduction to Manifolds}

1. Tu defines a differential 1-form on an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to be a function $\omega$ that assigns a point $p$ a covector $\omega_p \in T^*_p(\mathbb{R}^n):$
   \begin{align*}
   &\omega : U \rightarrow \bigcup_{p\in U} T^*_p(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
   \end{align*}
   \begin{align*}
   p \mapsto \omega_p \in T^*_p(\mathbb{R}^n)
   \end{align*}
   He soon defines that a 1-form $df$, the differential of $f$ as:
   \begin{align*}
   (df)_p(X_p) = X_pf
   \end{align*}
   My confusion is, how is this definition of $df$ in accordance with $\omega$? Shouldn't $X_pf \in T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?, this is not the dual space $T^*_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as described in $\omega$.
2. Proposition 4.1, which is immediately after the definition, it states that {$dx^1\rvert_p,...dx^n\rvert_p$} is the basis for the cotangent space $T^*_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and the proof of it is rather short:
   \begin{align*}
   (dx^i)_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\bigg\rvert_p)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\bigg\rvert_p x^i = \delta_j^i
   \end{align*}
   How does this close the proof? In order to show such is a basis, aren't we supposed to show that anything in the cotangent space is a linear combination of those, which are also independent?

Comment: $X_p\in T_p(\Bbb R^n)$, and $X_pf \in\Bbb R$.

Comment: oh darn, so true.